# Finding the matrix from the null space

Tags: linear-algebra

If I had a kernel as span of a line (4,7,0), how do I find the matrix from this kernel. Assume no rows and columns have been given for the matrix. I have been at this for days and am completely clueless.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the whole question, because if I understand your question correctly, there's no way to do this; there are infinitely many transformations (and matrices) whose kernel is this line. Are there any other pieces of information about this matrix?

Comment: Nope, none given. Just asked to find the matrix whose kernel is the span of the vector (4,7,0)

Comment: Wait, are you maybe expected just to give *an example* of such a matrix? If so, then this question can be answered.

Comment: You haven't *quoted* the problem.  Is it "find **a** matrix ..." or "find **the** matrix ...".

Comment: It is "a matrix such that .....kernel is spanned by the above vector". I believe there could be multiple solutions, right? I think the question assumes this and asks for any one that just satisfies the condition for the kernel

Comment: @Mather2905 Yes, there are multiple solutions. Another clarification: since the kernel is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$, the matrix must have $3$ columns. Does the question specify the number of rows? For example, is it specified that the matrix is square?

Comment: No, not specified that it is a square matrix and neither does it mention the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

To build such a matrix, first note that the nullspace of our matrix has dimension $1$ (it's spanned by a single non-zero vector), and the number of columns must be $3$ (since this single non-zero vector lives in $\Bbb{R}^3$). By the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of the matrix must be $3 - 1 = 2$. This implies that our matrix must contain at least $2$ rows (and only $2$ linearly independent rows).

Further, as Robert Israel points out, these rows must be orthogonal to $(4, 7, 0)$. The way matrix multiplication works is by a series of dot products, and multiplying a column vector to a matrix simply dot products this column with each row, forming a new column vector. Since multiplying the matrix with $(4, 7, 0)$ should produce the zero vector, each of these dot products must be zero.

So, let's build a $2 \times 3$ matrix, with two linearly independent rows (so that the rank is $2$), each of which is orthogonal to $(4, 7, 0)$ (so that the kernel contains $(4, 7, 0)$). By the rank-nullity theorem, the kernel of this matrix will be only $1$ dimension, and hence will be exactly equal to $\operatorname{span}(4, 7, 0)$.

Our two vectors can be $(7, -4, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$, for example. This gives us a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
7 & -4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

By the reasoning above, I'm confident that this matrix satisfies our conditions. But, I would suggest computing the general solution, and verifying that it comes to $\operatorname{span}(4, 7, 0)$.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! this made a lot of sense. I'm just a little unclear on why it's orthogonal to (4,7,0)? That part didn't make 100% sense. Could you please clarify? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Mather2905 Just compute, by regular matrix multiplication:$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4\\7\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4a+7b+0c\\4d+7e+0f\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(4,0,7)\cdot(a,b,c)\\(4,0,7)\cdot(d,e,f)\end{pmatrix}.$$Hopefully you can see how this generalises to matrices of different dimensions.

Comment: Okay yes this made it very clear! You should consider becoming a professor if you aren't already, you're a lot better than a lot of teachers I've come across. Thanks so much

Comment: @Mather2905 I'm trying. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all you know is the kernel, then you can't determine the matrix.  All you know is that each row is orthogonal to the kernel.

Comment: Hmm there is no other information given to us. Just asked to find the matrix whose kernel is the span of the vector (4,7,0). Any idea on a possible method of approaching this then?